IPC Shared Memory on Flutter
Is there a shared memory construct in Flutter?  Can that do multiple processes and handle large amounts of data (eg, 1 app to read the camera and stuff into framebuffer, every other app reads from a shared framebuffer)?  Is there a way I can tell OpenCV to stuff the frame into that page?
I saw https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/memory, but that seems "Android" and not cross-platform...
Is that different than opening a temporary file stream in one app and having everyone else open it for reading?  I'd rather not encode/decode a lot, but...

cross-platform? for this? I don't see any hope. you're doing highly system-specific operations there. anything "cross-platform" would have to handle each platform and its library versions specifically, hiding all of this from you. -- this is certainly out of scope for OpenCV, and nothing specific to OpenCV. its C++ API lets you wrap any memory into a cv::Mat. the rest is general C++ and system API usage.
